# Is convexity actually necessary for gradient descent?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, gradient, convex

I understand that the problem that when you are optimizing something using gradient descent, the algorithm might get stuck in a local optimum that isn't global. Otherwise, there are non-convex functions for which all local optima are also globally optima. Take the function $$f(x) = x^2 + 3\sin x$$ as an example.

My question therefore is: Why is the term *convex* used so often, when it is apparently a sufficient, but not necessary condition? What word is used to describe that each local optimum is also a global one?

Comment: Hi: If the problem is convex, this  guarantees that there's one optimum but it's not an only if. Also,  I don't think it says anything about not getting stuck at a local because a local is not a true optimum. Boyd's text probably discusses these issues in more depth.

Comment: I think it doesn't guarantee there is an optimum: the function f(x) = x is convex (even thought not strictly), but it doesn't have a minimum, only the infimum of negative infinity if you want to say so.

Comment: But thanks for the literature recommendation.

Comment: Generalizations of convexity have been formulated to address this question (understanding it is impossible to supply any necessary and sufficient condition for all local optima to be global).  Look up terms like "quasiconvex" and "pseudoconvex" for instance.

Comment: @Moritz: My apologies if what I said is wrong. I didn't know that convex didn't imply that. In fact, now you have me wondering what convex does imply !!!!!

Comment: @mlofton No problem. You can look up the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function. I'd summarize it saying that at no point, the function is curved downward, which for example is the case for f(x) = x

Comment: Hi Moritz: I looked at it and it says ( under functions of several variable ) that the local minimum of a convex function is also a global minimum. So, same would hold for max of the negative of the same function. This was what I was intending to convey ( because I thought that was what you were asking )  so, if I wasn't clear or that wasn't what you were asking , my bad. Thanks for link.